# Is there a way to apply a function using keywords?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a POAM for work where we work with multiple different clients that all have different guidelines. I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so in column B if there is this word then in column H a certain function is applied? For example if a client was called Big Company and they have a deadline for a report in x amount of days, is there a function for if Big Company X is present then cell H2=E2+30?

I am very inexperienced with Excel so explain it like I'm 5 years old please :)

Edit to add:
Here is a picture of basically what I'm working with, there are different clients for the same or different companies. Instead of formatting the each individual cell on different companies I would like a function that recognizes if it's a client for Big Company X then the report due will be date recieved plus 30 days. But if it's a client for Little Company Y then the report will be due in 90 days. Hopefully this clarifies a little bit. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM0Af.jpg)

Comment: You've basically said it yourself... start by using the `IF` function?

Comment: For a more detailed answer, it would be helpful to see some mock data and the expected outcome.

Comment: Either using IF or using a table reference lookup (if there are many different clients possible).